# The process cannot access the file 'bin\Debug\Employee_InfoMgmt.exe' because it is being used by another process

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       Unable to copy file "obj\Debug\Employee_InfoMgmt.exe" to "bin\Debug\Employee_InfoMgmt.exe". The process cannot access the file 'bin\Debug\Employee_InfoMgmt.exe' because it is being used by another process.   EmployeeManagement

Comment: Have you forgotten to close the program? (Check Task manager)

Comment: Does your project folder has some sort of sync on? Like Google Drive etc.?

Comment: @PoulBak I did not. This happens after I change something in my code and try to build and run and this error shows. restarting works but I don't wanna do that everytime

Comment: @maddy23285 no.

Comment: Close VS, delete .vs (hidden) folder, obj and bin folder. Open the project build again and check if it is still throwing error.

Comment: Are you building/debugging `Employee_InfoMgmt.exe`? You have to close the debug target before you try to recompile it

Comment: @maddy23285 I can't delete the bin folder

Comment: If you are doing any IO operation in your program, then check if they are disposed or closed after completion of task. Use finally block to close or dispose any open IO object. Because a system resource is still holding your program to either complete it's task or waiting to be released by the program

Comment: you might try https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer to find out what's blocking